# set pytest arg for tox but not direct pytest

Tags: pytest, tox

I'd tox to run pytest by default with some argument (`-n 2`) but I don't want that argument to be used by default if I just type `pytest ...` to run pytest directly. Is this possible?

If I include this:

```
[pytest]
addopts=-n 2
```

in `tox.ini`, then `tox` uses the option (as desired), but also makes `pytest` use the option if I just run `pytest ...` not through tox (not desired).

I tried adding a `pytest.ini`, but then the defaults in `tox.ini` aren't used at all (whether running via `tox` or not).

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The py.test docs describe [several ways to change configuration](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/customize.html#adding-default-options). One is to add flags in `tox.ini`, as you're already doing; another is to use environment variables:

> You can set a `PYTEST_ADDOPTS` environment variable to add command line options while the environment is in use:
>
> ```
> export PYTEST_ADDOPTS="-v"
> ```

So if you add the arguments in the `[tox]` block of your `tox.ini`; for example:

```
[tox]
setenv=
  PYTEST_ADDOPTS="-n 2"
```

and don't set the flag in the `[pytest]` block, you should only see those arguments applied when you’re running py.test with tox.

It’s a little inelegant, but I think it does the trick.

(And FWIW, I’ve tried making that changes in the [tox.ini for hypothesis-python](https://github.com/HypothesisWorks/hypothesis-python/pull/1122#issuecomment-366548229), and it has the desired effect.)